# Will I be able to get a US Business / Tourist VISA after a trip in Vietnam

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, tourist-visas

I am french and I have planned to visit Vietnam for a week or two with a tourist visa.

It seems like a silly question to me but I'd rather be sure. Somebody told me that if I visit this kind of country (country that have bad history with the US or communist countries) I might get in trouble if I want to obtain a business / tourist visa for the US later in my life.

Is this true? Can a visa request be denied or more difficult because I visited certain countries before in my life?

Edit: I have seen the duplicate, I understand that it can happen with some middle-east countries these days, but could it happen with some asia countries too? I get that there is no official list and that it depends alot of the immigration guy questionning you, but is Vietnam / Laos / China and other countries like that are as badly seen in the US as some of the middle-east countries?

Comment: The US has had full diplomatic relations with Communist Vietnam for ages now. It's not a problem.